# Fastest option for storing and retrieving objects in a list in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, multiplayer

Say I have a multiplayer game with like 100-1000 players on a server.

Consider the following options. Which would be the faster option for storing and retrieving players and is this difference meaningful or negligible?

Option 1:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

Option 2:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> usernamesToIds = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
List<Integer> availableIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>;
List<Integer> usedIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Player[] players = new Player[1000];
```

For option 1, any time you want to fetch a player, say by username, you have to iterate through the whole list until one matches, whereas with option 2 you can instantly fetch that player by getting their array index from the HashMap.

For iterating through the second array, I have the "usedIDs" list with all of the non-null indexes and you can just iterate through that list and access the array index from the list. Also, with option 1 if you remove a player from the list many of the other player's ids change.

Edit: Sorry, I added another list that I had, an "availableIDs" list. Whenever a player was added I removed an id from this list and put it in the "usedIDs" list, (and the opposite for when a player was removed) to keep assigning players free ids.

Comment: IMO Option 1, mainly because it's more organized (and maybe faster)

Comment: For 1000 entries you won't be able to see the difference in performance, although the `Map` is the way to go in general for key-based lookups.

Comment: Why not just have a map of user names to players `HashMap<String, Player>`?

Comment: Not sure why you need a list in option 2. Your hashmap would map username to Player object, not to the index that the player has in some auxiliary list. As a general rule, if you have to repeatedly search a list for the same item then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: If you wanted to also fetch the players by ids then maybe just the hashmap wouldn't be enough.

Comment: If you want to lookup by username and by userid then have two hashmaps. The collection of players remains the same. Just be sure to maintain them both e.g. if you remove a player from one hashmap, then remove that same player from the other.

Comment: How many users do you have now? I would do it the most obvious way for now (the easiest to debug) and then change it if you ever have speed problems. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting up to 1000 items in the list and the search will be occasional (e.g. triggered by user action) rather than continuous (e.g. run every 'frame' of the game) then there is really no need to do anything other than iterate through the list.

```
players.stream().filter(p -> p.getName().equals(searchName)).findFirst();
```

The performance gain of using a map is not worth the additional code complexity. Focus optimisation on areas where you can see (via a profiler) a real performance bottleneck.

If you do need additional performance, avoid the proposed indirection via an index. This is incredibly error prone (e.g. if you remove a player you need to reindex the map). Rather just map from the player's name to the player object.

```
Map<String,Player> players = new HashMap<>();
```

This could act as your primary collection for players. You can use it as a pure collection of players using `players.values()`.

If you are storing a separate collection of players you will need to ensure the integrity of the two stores: e.g. ensuring players are added and removed from both. So best avoided unless you really need it.